# Reopening closed question because the question was reformulated

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

I asked a question on stackoverflow, see link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839967/which-webtechnologies-are-used-for-building-websites-other-then-xhtml-markup-l

It was closed because it was vague, but I improved the question, so it should be reopened.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is still not focused and specific enough to be reopened. Your question is also off-topic for SO; it is not a practical problem you are facing with code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes agree with you.

Comment: And even if it did not face the problems as stated by Martijn, you are ultimately asking for a list of things. Which would be regarded as not-constructive. I don't see a way to save this particular question.

Answer (score 4):

No, it still clearly falls under "there is no actual problem to be solved".

See [the faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) for the full list:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed,
>   avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?” 0 your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more
>     answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - **there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”**
> - we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”

No need to reopen then. You can try flagging your own question, but most likely your flag will be declined.

Answer (score 2):

You changed the way the question is worded, but you really didn't address the content problem. There are lots of ways that you can provide content for your web pages: XML, RSS, JPEG, streaming video, PDF, etc. And there are all kinds of ways that you can encode your web pages and have them rendered in a form that browsers will understand (PHP, ASP, etc.).

The problem with your question is that nobody can tell what problem you're trying to solve, so it's impossible to know what the "correct" answer is. What's the problem with HTML? Why are you looking for an alternative? Are you writing a book and trying to catalog all the possible formats for web content? Building an Arduino-based web server that needs the most compact format known to man?

It's better to ask the question that you're really trying to answer than to ask for a list of the entire range of possible answers.

Comment: I was just curious. And people downvoted my question which prevented me from asking a new question. It would be nice to ask questions again. So I need some votes to delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply flag your own question to re-open after editing. Just Click on the flag link, select other option and describe why you want to open. This flag will directly goes to moderator's flag list and a moderator can re-open the question if it is an valid question.